# yahoo pipes open password protected xml via port 8184

Tags: php, xml, pipe, yahoo

I want to automatically download an xml feed from a server say every minute. The file containing the feed is password protected. Opening a url like http://username:password@xyz.com:8184/feed/ gives me the xml data in my web browser.

How ever when I try to fetch the data using Yahoo Pipes I get a 502 error. Using the url example metioned before the pipe works fine until the feed fetch operator comes into play and I get a 502 error. I use a copy of this pipe http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=e9eb03e3173dfa7dce69bee0c589a619

I have also tried it in php. Put i still run into an authorization error.

Could it be I need to find a solution for the fact that I need to connect to port 8184? And if so, what would that solution be? Google is giving me a hard time finding it.

Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Comment: Please contact the vendor of the Yahoo Pipes software to obtain support and help venues for that software. Asking here on Stackoverflow is just the wrong venue, we do not run Yahoo Pipes nor can we inspect the source-code of it to tell you exactly what triggers a 502 in Yahoo Pipes.

Comment: Also you might run into the problem using the wrong search terms in google. If you're stuck with googling, differ search terms a bit more. Also try to find out if you're using the right terms for your search by constuling Yahoo Pipes manual and forums first.